# I want to get all select options without an empty value then clone them on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get all select options without an empty value then clone them on change event. I is this possible ?

This is my code:

```
 $(function() {
        $("#ddlSecurityQuestions1").change(function() {                     
        var index = $(this).val();
        $('#ddlSecurityQuestions2').empty();           
        $('#ddlSecurityQuestions1 option').clone().appendTo('#ddlSecurityQuestions2');            
        var otherDropDown=document.getElementById('ddlSecurityQuestions2');            
         otherDropDown.options.remove(index);             
      });
  });
```

Comment: The values have numbers, which are being used as an index.

Comment: **if (!index){}** will equate to true if the value is nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#ddlSecurityQuestions1").change(function () {

    var $options = $(this).find('option').filter(function () {
        return this.value !== '';
    }).clone();

    $('#ddlSecurityQuestions2').empty();
    $options.appendTo('#ddlSecurityQuestions2');
});
```